# Finding the distribution of a transformed random vector

Tags: probability-theory

I am working on problem in my book, and I am having trouble determining the domain on which the transformed density function is defined. The random vector ((X, Y, Z)) has the density function given by:

$$ f(x, y, z) = (y - z) e^{-x}, \quad 0 \leqslant x, \ 0 \leqslant y \leqslant x, \ 0 \leqslant z \leqslant y. $$

I am asked to find the distribution of the variable (W = X - Y + Z) after a transformation ((u, v, w) = (x, y, -u + v + w_i)). The Jacobian of this transformation is found to be (1), and the density function of the transformed vector ((U, V, W)) is given by:

$$ g(u, v, w) = f(u, v, -u + v + w) = (u - v) e^{-w}. $$
However, I am having difficulty determining the domain on which (g) is defined. The inequalities are as follows (this is solution, but I can't figure how to do it for other excersises):

$$ \begin{align*}
&0 \leqslant x \quad 0 \leqslant u \quad 0 \leqslant w \\
&0 \leqslant y \leqslant x \Longleftrightarrow \quad 0 \leqslant v \leqslant u \quad \omega \leqslant u \\
&0 \leqslant z \leqslant y \quad u - v \leqslant w \leqslant u \quad u - w \leqslant v \leqslant u \\
\end{align*} $$

I have calculated the marginal distribution with respect to (w) as:

$$ g_w(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u, v, w) dv = \int_w^{\infty} du \int_{u-w}^u (u - w) e^{-w} dv = \int_w^{\infty} w(u - w) e^{-u} du = w e^{-w}, \quad w \geqslant 0. $$

Any guidance on how determin the valid range for (w) or any corrections to my approach would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!